# DNN doesn't redirect to Default.aspx

Tags: redirect, iis-6, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN site (5.06) that I developed on a standalone machine running IIS7. When I copied the site to the production machine running IIS6 and enter the URL, such as `www.site.com`, I get a generic DNN error page with no additional information. However, if I add the default page, `www.site.com/Default.aspx` everything works fine.

The Friendly URL settings were never changed and I've verified Default.aspx is entered on the Documents tab in IIS6. The portal event viewer has no entry for the error page I get.

I'm nearly certain it has to do with migrating from IIS7 to II6; clearly I'm missing something here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNN has confirmed this is an error in 5.06, and will be addressed in a future update. That doesn't help me today, but I was able to work around the problem by adding the following to the Friendly URLs list:

```
Look for: .*/
Send To:  ~/Default.aspx
```

I can't find the forum thread I was reading yesterday, but did find this one which also goes into detail on the issue: [Error upgrading from 5.5.1 to 5.6.0](http://web3.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/107/threadid/396022/scope/posts/threadpage/1/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty odd...

Double check PortalAlias table in your SQL server. Confirm www.site.com is in there.
Double check host headers in IIS6 has www.site.com
Make sure Default.aspx is in the documents area of IIS6 and set as the top default to run
Recycle your app pool

cross your fingers

Only thing I ever run into from IIS6 and IIS7 is in the app pool running in Integrated mode or classic... but that is usually as issue going from IIS6 to 7, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue (for me) by taking the web.config file from a working site with the same version of DotNetNuke and modifying it to have the correct machine key and connection strings. This is my last resort when DotNetNuke is being strange. I am running 10+ DNN sites at version 5.6.0 and I only encountered this issue once.